# Ruby: NoMethodError in BusinessAndUnitsController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to created a multi-layered controller inside my app.

with the following structure :

--Business_and_units_controller *(main controller)*

--↳ Business_units_controller *( sub controller )*

----↳ Business_managers_controller *( sub controller to Business_units_controller )*

----↳ Business_divisions_controller *( sub controller to Business_units_controller )*

----↳ business_units_strats_attributes_controller *( sub controller to Business_units_controller )*

It's pretty complex and maybe overly?

Anyways, I've created the controller called:

```
business_and_units_controller.rb
```

with a model:

```
business_and_unit.rb
```

I've added the controller to my **routes.rb** *(to test it and see if it works)*

```
  get    '/testunit',  to: 'business_and_units#index'
  resources :business_and_units
```

After seeing if the code worked i got the following error:

```
NoMethodError in BusinessAndUnitsController#index
undefined method `businessandunits' for #<User:0x007f55666f2a58>

Extracted source (around line #6):
1
2             
3  
4   def index
6    @business_and_units = current_user.businessandunits
7    
8   end
```

I understand that the cause of the problem is that my business_and_units is not defined. But i don't understand why it isn't defined.

Can any of you see the cause of my problem?

---

To summarize:

My **problem**: according to ruby my business_and_units_controller.rb is not defined in the index.

**Goal** of this post: To understand why it isn't defined.

---

ps: I've searched for numerous similar posts in search to the solution of my problem, but haven't been able to find a solution.

my **controller file**

```
class BusinessAndUnitsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy

    def index
     @business_and_units = current_user.business_and_units

    end

    def show
      @business_and_units = Business_and_unit.find_by(id: params[:id])
      if !@business_and_unit
        raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
      end
      @user = @business_and_unit.user
    end

    def new
      @user = User.new
      @business_and_unit = Business_and_unit.new
    end

    def edit
      @business_and_unit = Business_and_unit.find(params[:id])
    end

    def create
      @business_and_unit = current_user.business_and_units.build(business_and_unit_params)
      if @business_and_unit.save
        flash[:success] = "business_and_unit created!"
        redirect_to @business_and_unit
      else
        @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
        render 'new'
      end
    end

    def update
      @business_and_unit = Business_and_unit.find(params[:id])
      if @business_and_unit.update(business_and_unit_params)
        redirect_to @business_and_unit
      else
        render 'edit'
      end
    end

    def destroy
      @business_and_unit.destroy
      flash[:success] = "business_and_unit deleted"
      redirect_to business_and_units_path
    end

    private

    def business_and_unit_params
      params.require(:business_and_unit).permit( 
      :corporate_strategy,  :future_sale_value,
      :industry, :market_focus, :business_unit,

      business_units_attributes: [
      :id, :business_units,
      :_destroy],

       business_managers_attributes: [
      :id, :business_managers,
      :_destroy],

       business_divisions_attributes: [
      :id, :business_divisions,
      :business_divisions_managers,
      :_destroy],

       business_units_strats_attributes: [
      :id, :business_units_strats,
      :_destroy])
    end

    def correct_user
      @business_and_unit = current_user.business_and_units.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to business_and_units_path if @business_and_unit.nil?
    end

end
```

Comment: The error message (which complaints about `current_user.businessandunits`) and the code you provided (which looks like this `current_user.business_and_units` at that line in question) do not match. How does your `User` model look like? Is there q method `businessandunits` or `business_and_units` defined?

Comment: @spickermann Hey thank you for your response. It seems Andere answerd the question! But you where going into the same direction. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with your controller.

The error is that there is no method `#businessandunits` in your `User` model.

Based on the information you provided, I think you missed a relation definition `has_many :business_and_units` in your `User` class.

Then you will be able to call `current_user.business_and_units`

Comment: Thank you Andre! It seems it was a quick oversight on my part. The user class was indeed missing  the has many part!